# How can i use methods which are in cogs folder on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to use one of the methods of cogs(I mean there is a folder which is called cogs) on discord.py.But I can not use these methods.[Names of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj3BX.png)

By the way,I've always been using to get inside of cogs:

```
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")  
@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```

So without these code lines is there another way that I can use cogs' methods?

Comment: What do you mean with "methods inside of cogs"? What do these cogs look like? Because a cog file should just contain `setup` and an instance of `Cog` which has commands, no methods.

Comment: @stijndcl Yeah you're right.I wanted to say methods.So as you can see in the photo there is a **main.py** module and i want to use cogs' methods in this module.My question is is there another different way than above the code.If you answer me,I'll be greatful.Thank you

Comment: If you want to use methods defined in those files then you just have to import them, load_extension is to add a `Cog` with `Commands` to your `Bot`. If you want to ask if there's another way to add a Cog to a bot, then why exactly do you need another way? This does everything it could ever do which is add the cog & its commands, what more functionality are you looking for?

Comment: @stijndcl Okey got it thank you.